# How to add failure description to GitLab notification mail?

Tags: notifications, gitlab

I have a project with a pipeline in GitLab and I enabled notification mails if the pipeline fails.

This is how my notification looks right now:

[image: notification]

On the GitLab website I get this nice failure summery:

[image: failure]

How can I modify or extend the modification mail to also include the failure?
It would be nice to see the actual cause of the failure without a check in on the website.

Comment: do you have admin access to gitlab ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Job logs in the Failed Pipeline notification emails were intentionally removed by the GitLab team in September 2020. Here's the [Merge Request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/42395) that implemented the change. This was in the 13.4.0 release created 2020-09-22. The [Changelog](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed-153-changes-30-of-them-are-from-the-community) says: `Remove job logs from notification e-mails. !42395`

Their listed reasons were:

- Often more than 30 lines are needed to understand a build failure.
- These logs could leak sensitive information.
- The notification e-mails are scheduled around the same time when the
  job log is archived to object storage, so the notification service may
  need to read from a shared volume (NFS). There are race conditions when
  the file has been archived, and we have to retry when these happen